# Syntax for inserting multiple records into a table with one insert command?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm writing a stored procedure where I'm declaring a temporary table. I need to query multiple rows from the database into that table from a query that I've already written. Then I'm doing another query of that temp table. The reason why is lengthy to explain but it's basically a work-around. Anyways...

The actual query is too lengthy to put here but it's basically like this.

```
DECLARE @a TABLE
(
    Museum VARCHAR(32),
    MuseumID INT, 
    Country VARCHAR(32),
    City VARCHAR(32),
    Paintings VARCHAR(32),
    Sculptures VARCHAR(32)
);
```

Now I need to insert rows into this temp table:

I tried this but I don't think it will work

```
INSERT INTO @a VALUES
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
           TOP (100) PERCENT dbo.Museum.Museum,
                             dbo.Musuem.MuseumID,
                             dbo.World. Country,

            BLAH BLAH BLAH FROM AND WHERE JUNK
 )
```

How can I insert the queried rows from my query into @a?

Please help thanks.

I also tried BULK INSERT but I don't think I'm doing the syntax right. If anyone could help that would be awesome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with `INSERT ... SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO @a 
    SELECT DISTINCT
            dbo.Museum.Museum,
                             dbo.Musuem.MuseumID,
                             dbo.World. Country,

            BLAH BLAH BLAH FROM AND WHERE JUNK
```

`TOP 100 PERCENT` is absolutely meaningless. Why is it there?

Comment: I dunno, that's some goofy standard they make us put on there. What does it even do I'm afraid to remove it.

Comment: By the way does that DECLARE look familiar?

Comment: It means to put all the records in there.  Top is a limiter to how many records are returned. IE Top 1 returns only the first row. Obviously limiting to top 100% is meaningless That is ALL the records.

Comment: @Jordan I know what top does, but my point was, what does `TOP 100 PERCENT` do that simply leaving it out doesn't? It was a rhetorical question. As I suggested it was meaningless, and it is. My question wasn't what does it do, it was why is it there?

Comment: @ Aaron The TOP (100) PERCENT, the prof make us put that on almost all queries in SQL Server 2008.

Comment: @AaronBertrand i was telling the OP what it does not you lol.
he/she said I dunno why it's there so I figured an explanation was in order